# Is it possible to plot complex variable in wxMaxima or Octave?

Tags: octave, maxima

For example , if I want to plot Sin(z) where z is a complex variable , how I will achieve it in either Octave or Maxima?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Octave, but here is a message about that, with some code you can try in Maxima: https://www.ma.utexas.edu/pipermail/maxima/2007/006644.html

There may be more specific information for wxMaxima -- you can try their user forum: https://sourceforge.net/p/wxmaxima/discussion/435775/

Answer (score 1):

(referring Octave 4.0.0)

How do you want to try to represent the output of the function?  Plotting either the real or imaginary parts of the output can be done fairly simply using a 3-dimensional graph, where the x and y axes are the real and imaginary components of z, and the vertical axis is either the real or imaginary values of sin(z).  Producing those are fairly simple in Octave. Here's a link to a script you can save and run to show an example.

Simply change the g = exp(f) line to g = sin(f).

[Octave-help mailing list example](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Plotting-functions-of-complex-variable-tt4646015.html)

Note that the imaginary part plot is commented out. Just switch the # between the different plot commands if you want to see that part.

Now, are you instead looking for options to map the Z plane (z=x+iy) to the W plane (w=u+iv) and represent closed contours mapped by w=sin(z)?  in that case you'll need to do parametric plotting as described on [this FIT site](http://my.fit.edu/~gabdo/introduc.html). There is a link to his Matlab program at the bottom of the explanation that provides one method of using color coding to match z->w plane contour mapping.

Those m-files are written for Matlab, so a few things do not work, but the basic plotting is compatible with Octave 4.0.0.  (the top level ss13.m file will fail on calls to flops and imwrite)

But, if you put your desired function in myfun13.m for f, df and d2f, (sin(z), cos(z), -sin(z) respectively), then run cvplot13, you'll get color maps showing the correspondence between z and w planes.

Answer (score 1):

wxMaxima has a plot3d that can do it. Since the expression to plot is in terms of x and y, I plotted the function's magnitude with `abs(f(x+%i*y))`:

```
plot3d(abs((x+%i*y-3)*(x+%i*y-5)*(x+%i*y-6)), [x,2,7], [y,-1,1],  [grid,100,100], [z,0,5])$
```

[image: wxmaxima plot]